# Strpos not returning the expected result (and not FALSE)

Tags: php

I made a function to check if the word "HELPER" is included into the string, if I var_dump it, it will return: `int(0)` which means it found the word HELPER otherwise it returns as false.

I use the following code:

```
if(strpos($result['attributes'], 'HELPER') !== false)
{   
   $CookiesExpire = time() + $cookie_time;
   setcookie ($cookie_name, 'Flags='.$result['flags'].'&Exp='.$CookiesExpire.'', $CookiesExpire);
   header('Location: mainPage.php');
   die;
}else
{
   $_SESSION['login']['failed'] = true;
   header('Location: login.php');
   die;
}
```

This continues to skip the if statement and go straight to the else statement even though the result is true because it found "HELPER" into the string.

`$results['attributes']` a string with the value HELPER|ADMINHELPER|MODERATOR

Now I can resolve this issue by doing an explode, however I have no idea why this code doesn't work and would like to find out why.

It might also be worth mentioning that I used the exact code in PHP Laravel which did work.

Comment: `explode()` and `in_array()` is a better solution, as it would do a full string check. I.e., a user with only `ADMINHELPER` will also match `HELPER` even though they don't have that attribute.

Comment: You're right that it might be a better solution, I don't actually use helper and adminhelper but it's an example not to show the actual values. I am wondering why this code in particular does not work.

Comment: @Mik3NL Are you certain $result["attributes"] has the string you think it does? And are you certain the problem is with the if statement and not your session logic? I don't see you calling session_start here -- and you don't set any $_SESSION values if it's true.

Comment: I'm a 100% sure that result contains that, I even var_dumped it and it resulted in this: ```string(28) "HELPER|ADMINHELPER|MODERATOR"```. The session is being started at the top of the page which works fine, all works fine except this part.